# Change style in CSS by character class

Tags: css, internationalization

I am trying to localize a website, and there's one block of HTML that I want to tweak so I can store just the text (no formatting) in the message resource

```
View <b>11</b> new out of <b>11</b> message(s) in your inbox
```

What I'd like to do is somehow with CSS render numbers to be bold without having to explicitly put in tags in the message bundle.

Is that possible to do without JavaScript but still have it work with Chrome, Firefox, Safari or Edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do without JavaScript if you've got two different fonts you can use. You pick out the digits using a unicode-range, Like this: (Not tested in Safari, but works OK in the others)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Archivo';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Archivo Regular'), local('Archivo-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/archivo/v6/k3kQo8UDI-1M0wlSfdfoLnnA.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Archivo Black';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Archivo Black Regular'), local('ArchivoBlack-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/archivoblack/v9/HTxqL289NzCGg4MzN6KJ7eW6CYyF_g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+30-39;
}

div {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', 'Archivo', sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<div>View 11 new out of 11 message(s) in your inbox</div>
```

Comment: nice, yucky but nice :D I don't think I need to use "Archivo"  on the font family but have a custom font family can I?

Comment: Yes. Archivo's just an example.

Answer (score -1):

To make the numbers bold, you can use the regex replace and detect the numbers then add the bold tags like the **following code:**

> Sorry I noticed now that you don't want to use jquery, I'm not sure if it is doable with css only.

```js
$('#block').html(function(i, c) {
  return c.replace(/\d+/g, function(v) {
    return "<b>" + v + "</b>";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
  View 11 new out of 11 message(s) in your inbox
</div>
```